# Stop the Error List from popping up in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, settings, markup

Whenever I type in the markup of an aspx/ascx page in Visual Studio, the Error List window pops up (blank of course).  Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't happen all the time.  I cannot reproduce the behavior you are describing today, but I've seen it before.  Can't remember why though!

Comment: I have the same problem - but it just started.  I just installed resharper 6.0 and chirpy.  I haven't figured out if it is related to either of those.  unchecking Always show error list if build finishes with errors did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Super wild guess: in `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General`, just clear the `Always show Error list if build finishes with errors` check mark.